# How to know Unity Build application is 32bit or 64bit

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to add update function to my application depend on its own version(32bit or 64 bit). Is there some function that  I can know my application(build from unity) is 32 bit or 64bit?

Thank You EveryOne !

Comment: `IntPtr.Size` returns 8 when the app is 64 bit and 4 when the app is 32 bit.

Comment: Thank u, it works well!

Answer (score 3):

As "Programmer" said... evaluating IntPtr.Size is the way to go.  Here's a full example of how we detect the current UI version in our application:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
this.uiType = "UNITY-EDITOR";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
this.uiType = "UNITY-ANDROID";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
this.uiType = "UNITY-IOS";
#elif UNITY_STANDALONE_LINUX
this.uiType = "UNITY-LINUX";
#elif UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX
this.uiType = "UNITY-MAC";
#elif UNITY_WEBGL
this.uiType = "UNITY-WEBGL";
#elif UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
  this.uiType = "UNITY-WINDOWS64";
else
  this.uiType = "UNITY-WINDOWS";
#else
Debug.LogError("Bad Version detected! (is this a new UI build?)");
#endif
```